# What is difference between class path , file system?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know that:

1. `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");`

   loads context definition from an XML file located in the classpath, treating context definitions as classpath resources.
2. `ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");`

   loads context definition from an XML file in the filesystem.
3. `XmlWebApplicationContext`

   loads context definition from an XML file contained within a web application.

But, what does it exactly mean??

Thanks :)

Comment: You already described how they are different in usage.  Internally they have different behaviors like XmlWebApplicationContent by default will look for applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF folder.  And also it takes init parameter for configuring different location.  Basically they will use different approaches to load the XML files.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` will read files from your classpath. They must be in `classes` folder of your web application or in a `jar` in your `lib`folder.
- `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` can access all your file system, for example `c:/config/applicationContext.xml`.
- `XmlWebApplicationContext` certainly can access to files contained in your web application, but this is not the most important thing. It implements [WebApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) and this means that it will detect [ServletContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html) beans, register custom scopes (request, session, ...) among other things.

Comment: That's I want exactly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

FileSystemXmlApplicationContext- You need to provide complete full path of xml bean
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - In this case you DONOT need to set full path, as long as classpath is set

Answer (score 0):

I think above opinion may have something wrong, `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` **can not access your whole file system**, what it can only scan is your whole project folder.In order to prove my conclusion i make a example, first using `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext` and everything is normal, the second time i move beans.xml file to my desktop folder, so there is no beans.xml file in the project hirachy, and change ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to `FileSytemXmlApplicationContext` and something goes wrong, error trace below:

```
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [/Users/crabime/Development/IdeaProjects/springInterview/Users/crabime/Desktop/beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [/Users/crabime/Development/IdeaProjects/springInterview/Users/crabime/Desktop/beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Users/crabime/Desktop/beans.xml (No such file or directory)
```

So FileSystemXmlApplicationContext can only detect the current project all folder. For example you make a directory which named `config` under the project root directory, and you can change your Main Class code like below:

```
ApplicationContext atx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/config/beans.xml");
```

And everything will ok again. So if all like sinuhepop said i think there should something need to be changed.