# Where to put Spring applicationContext.xml in a non-web application?

Tags: java, spring

I am creating an application which uses Spring beans and I need to initialize `ApplicationContext` from `xml`. As it is not a server application, it doesn't have `WEB-INF` folder.So, where I should put the `xml` file?

Answer (score 3):

The spring documentation for this topic is a little overwhelming at first. A handy starting point in the spring documentation for application context config is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-instantiation)

A [file system xml application context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html) is probably the easiest to start with. So:

```
ApplicationContext appCtx = 
    new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/path/to/springconfig.xml");
```

Use `ClassPathApplicationContext` if you have the xml configuration in your application class path. In this example it might be a springconfig.xml under a project directory src/config/springconfig.xml.

```
ApplicationContext appCtx = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/springconfig.xml");
```

If you are unsure where your springconfig.xml ends up after you have built your application, you can use the following command to list the contents of your jar:

```
jar -tvf myapp.jar
```

For a default eclipse java project, the **project-home/bin** directory is the start of the classpath.

A related question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412225/what-is-difference-between-class-path-file-system)

Comment: I did the same and put application context xml in src directory. It does not work. I am working on Eclipse RCP application.

Comment: Updated to include some class path debug ideas. I tested this with Eclipse using src/config/springconfig.xml and it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html):

```
ApplicationContext ctx = 
  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Or consider migrating to [`@Configuration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html):

```
ApplicationContext ctx = 
  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
```

where `AppConfig` is annotated with `@Configuration` and no XML is needed.

Comment: I did the same and put application context xml in src directory. It does not work

Comment: @itun: please explain "*does not work*". If you are using [tag:maven], the `applicationContext.xml` should be in `src/main/resources`. If not - somewhere in the root directory of your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

Check this example [Spring Setter Injection](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-bean-setter-injection-1.html)

If the XML is in the applications classpath then use like this

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

Otherwise if the XML is in File system then use

```
     ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```