# context.xml file not found

Tags: java, xml, spring, intellij-idea

In Spring framework for Java, I create my beans using context.xml file and then load it with `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");`.

My program throws an exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`.

The file exists. I use Gradle for dependencies management and my src folder (where the file is) is marked as resource in Intellij. I understand that for some reason even though my src folder should be included in classpath variable, gradle run task just can't grab it from here.

When I use `new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");` instead everything works just fine, but I do need to use "Classpath" for my assignment.

English is not my native language.

This is my "Main" class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
    }
}
```

This is my beans from context.xml file

```
<bean id="t1000" class="by.zti.main.impl.T1000">
    <constructor-arg ref="sonyHead"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="toshibaLeg"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sonyHead" class="by.zti.main.impl.SonyHead"/>
<bean id="sonyLeg" class="by.zti.main.impl.SonyLeg"/>
<bean id="toshibaHead" class="by.zti.main.impl.ToshibaHead"/>
<bean id="toshibaLeg" class="by.zti.main.impl.ToshibaLeg"/>
```

This is my build.gradle file

```
group 'zti.spring.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'by.zti.main.Main'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-gradle'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile fileTree(dir:'src', includes:  ['/*.xml,/*.properties'])
}
```

Exception text

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at by.zti.main.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 13 more
```

This is my file tree from my project

[image]

Content of my classpath

```
/C:/Users/Cvazer/IdeaProjects/spring-test/build/classes/main/
/C:/Users/Cvazer/IdeaProjects/spring-test/build/resources/main
/C:/Users/Cvazer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.3.6.RELEASE/5f3041020113e3202a7ae9defe36e7b5d2fb87eb/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
/C:/Users/Cvazer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.3.6.RELEASE/d70b2393d380cd468d9a14969efaf9022c67c0/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
/C:/Users/Cvazer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.3.6.RELEASE/1585715ed598b76a23dac931c27aa039b189eafb/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
/C:/Users/Cvazer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.3.6.RELEASE/690da099c3c2d2536210f0fd06ff3f336de43ad9/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
/C:/Users/Cvazer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.3.6.RELEASE/13b53568cfd7b308e70efcbac6cdd0c5d597ba1/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
/C:/Users/Cvazer/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/4bfc12adfe4842bf07b657f0369c4cb522955686/commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

Comment: This link could help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412225/what-is-difference-between-class-path-file-system

Comment: I think this is classpath issue. Could you put the context.xml in src/main/resources folder. If you prefer existing folder structue then make sure the path is recognized by classpath

Comment: "src folder is marked as resource" - there's the problem, the resources folder should be "src/main/resources"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring cannot find bean xml configuration file when it does exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893760/spring-cannot-find-bean-xml-configuration-file-when-it-does-exist)

Answer (score 0):

I thin you should put the file in `src/main/resources/` OR specify another path `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("src/main/resources/blablabla/context.xml")`

Comment: `src` should not be on the classpath, your alternate example is incorrect

Comment: @OrangeDog Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893760/spring-cannot-find-bean-xml-configuration-file-when-it-does-exist

Comment: Yes, those answers are bad too.

Comment: Those answers are marked as useful, I don't think all people who voted up are wrong... There are probably many seniors who have seen that...

Comment: They're upvoted because they made the code work. They can still be wrong. The `src/main/resources` directory is a source directory, it's not supposed to be on the classpath and you're not supposed to load resources from there.

Answer (score 0):

you should append "file:" ie your url should be like this "file:src/main/resources/filename.xml"